# In asp.net, does the the JIT compiler noramlly just comile the IL code once or it compiles every time a page is requested?

Tags: asp.net

I suspect the former case. If so, don't you think the JIT name is misleading?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the jit is hybrid in nature, one of the reasons to its name.

Basically it uses a v-Table where all the functions are mapped into during its first run. The jit then determines whether to compile on the basis of whether they are statically described or not. The statically compiled code is cached & not compiled again but other than that the, it runs the normal translation every time.

So It is not whether it compiles once or every time but the fact that it runs & determines what to compile & what not to every time **Just in time** during run time.

Comment: Hi thanks.Any idea what criteria the JIT compiler uses to decide which code has to be compiled again?